# EWS: Changing owner of existing appointment

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am trying to set item of an existing appointment as owner and I am using something like following Xml request to that:

```xml
<ns1:UpdateItem xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone">
    <ns1:ItemChanges>
        <ns2:ItemChange>
            <ns2:ItemId Id="AAMkADY1ZDIwNjM1LTU4MjAtNGQy...ogbn8LT58s6MSx+1IiAZWtaUhFAACF1Gogbn8LT58s6MSx+1IiAZ3GKIJbAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAACF1Gogbn8LT58s6MSx+1IiAZ3HHOPj"/>
            <ns2:Updates>
                <ns2:SetItemField>
                    <ns2:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertyId="33321" PropertyType="Boolean"/>
                    <ns2:CalendarItem>
                        <ns2:ExtendedProperty>
                            <ns2:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertyId="33321" PropertyType="Boolean"/>
                            <ns2:Value>true</ns2:Value>
                        </ns2:ExtendedProperty>
                    </ns2:CalendarItem>
                </ns2:SetItemField>
                <ns2:SetItemField>
                    <ns2:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertyId="33303" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                    <ns2:CalendarItem>
                        <ns2:ExtendedProperty>
                            <ns2:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="Appointment" PropertyId="33303" PropertyType="Integer"/>
                            <ns2:Value>1</ns2:Value>
                        </ns2:ExtendedProperty>
                    </ns2:CalendarItem>
                </ns2:SetItemField>
            </ns2:Updates>
        </ns2:ItemChange>
    </ns1:ItemChanges>
</ns1:UpdateItem>
```

I need your help to use EWS API instead to make this call instead of SOAP call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition definition;
definition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Appointment, 33321, MapiPropertyType.Boolean);
appointment.SetExtendedProperty(definition, true);
definition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Appointment, 33303, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
appointment.SetExtendedProperty(definition, 1);
appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```